# Ratio of total energy to kinetic energy in hydrogen atom when the reference is changed

Tags: energy, atomic-structure

> If in the hydrogen atom potential energy at $\infty$ is chosen to be $\pu{13.6 eV},$ then what is the ratio of total energy and kinetic energy (with the sign) for the first Bohr orbit?

I think we don't consider the reference frame, and I answered with the relation

$$E_\mathrm{tot} : E_\mathrm{k} : E_\mathrm{p} = -1 : 1 : -2,$$

but the answer given is zero. Why?

Comment: What would be the potential energy of the 1st orbit _in this reference frame_? Then what would be the total energy?

Comment: P.E = $-13.6$eV in this frame. But would the K.E be still the same?

Comment: Of course K.E. will be still the same, _but P.E. will not_. In particular, it won't be -13.6 (it was like that when we had $0$ at $\infty$, which is not the case anymore).

Comment: Potential energy would be $-27.2$eV in the normal case. In this reference, it would be $-13.6$eV.

Comment: Sure. My fault, I confused it with the total energy. Well, anyway, K.E. stays the same as P.E. changes; what will happen to the total energy and the ratio?

Comment: T.E would be zero! So, the ratio would be zero.

Comment: So, is the ratio of all those quantities true only when we consider the potential at $\infty$ to be zero?

Comment: If you are talking about the virial theorem, then yes, it only applies when we have $0$ at $\infty$.